# One To Many Connection

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So I have two models Field and Sensor which have a OneToMany connection. Im creating a page where I have all the fields and whenever i click on one i get its respective sensors. I've made 4 test sensors (3 of them are on Field1, 1 on Field2) but its printing first one to first field and 2nd one to 2nd field maybe because of the pk parameter. Any clue how to fix that ?

```
class Field(models.Model):

    friendly_name = models.CharField(max_length=24, blank=True)
    soil_type = models.CharField(max_length=24, choices=SOIL_TYPES, blank=True) 
    cultivation = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=CULTIVATIONS, blank=True) 


class TreeSensor(models.Model):

    field = models.ForeignKey(Field, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    sensor_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
```

View :

```
def detail(request, field_id):
        try:
            sensor = models.TreeSensor.objects.get(pk=field_id)
        except models.TreeSensor.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("No sensors for this field")
        return render(request, 'dashboard/detail.html', {'sensor': sensor})
```

html:

```
<h1> {{ field.friendly_name}}</h1>
    {% for sensor in field.treesensor_set.all %}
        {{treesensor.sensor_name}}
        {%endfor%}
```

Comment: In the view you are showing, you are sending in one specific sensor, `sensor = models.TreeSensor.objects.get(pk=field_id)`, but in the HTML you show, you are using the field variable, as in `{{ field.friendly_name }}`.  Please add the view where the field variable is sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what does this line will print out?  and what is "**models**" in that case mean!

```
models.TreeSensor.objects.get(pk=field_id)
```

however, if you passed field_id which means the id of the Field model so, I think you can replace that filtering instead:

```
TreeSensor.objects.filter(field__pk=field_id)
```

Comment: btw `models` is a reference becuase I imported all the models and not the specific one so i used it this way to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that seemed to do the trick I also changed my template

```html
 {% for sensor in sensor %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ sensor.sensor_name}}</li>
    </ul>
 {%endfor%}
```

and view :

```py
def detail(request, field_id):
    try:
        sensor = models.TreeSensor.objects.filter(field__pk=field_id)
    except sensor.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("No sensors for this field")
    return render(request, 'dashboard/detail.html', {'sensor': sensor})
```

I get the right sensors on the right fields but if a field is empty the http404 does not raise an error.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the `does.not.exist`?How to just check for an empty query and print out the corresponding text?  Thanks